# How to 4 dimension PyTorch tensor multiply by 1 dimension tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I'm trying to write function for mixup training. On this [site](https://github.com/hongyi-zhang/mixup) i found some code and adapted to my previous code. But in original code only one random variable is generated for batch (64). But i want random value for every picture in batch. 
Code with one variable for batch:

```py
def mixup_data(x, y, alpha=1.0):
    lam = np.random.beta(alpha, alpha)
    batch_size = x.size()[0]
    index = torch.randperm(batch_size)

    mixed_x = lam * x + (1 - lam) * x[index,:]
    mixed_y = lam * y + (1 - lam) * y[index,:]

    return mixed_x, mixed_y
```

x and y for input come from pytorch DataLoader.
x input size: `torch.Size([64, 3, 256, 256])`
y input size: `torch.Size([64, 3474])`

This code works good. Then I changed it to this:

```py
def mixup_data(x, y):
    batch_size = x.size()[0]
    lam = torch.rand(batch_size)
    index = torch.randperm(batch_size)

    mixed_x = lam[index] * x + (1 - lam[index]) * x[index,:]
    mixed_y = lam[index] * y + (1 - lam[index]) * y[index,:]

    return mixed_x, mixed_y
```

But it gives an error: `RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (64) must match the size of tensor b (256) at non-singleton dimension 3`

How i understand how the code works is it takes first image in batch and multiply by first value in `lam` tensor (64 values long). How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the following line:

```
lam = torch.rand(batch_size)
```

by

```
lam = torch.rand(batch_size, 1, 1, 1)
```

With your current code, `lam[index] * x` multiplication is not possible because `lam[index]` is of size `torch.Size([64])` whereas `x` is of size `torch.Size([64, 3, 256, 256])`. So, you need to make the size of `lam[index]` as `torch.Size([64, 1, 1, 1])` so that it becomes broadcastable.

To cope with the following statement:

```
mixed_y = lam[index] * y + (1 - lam[index]) * y[index, :]
```

We can reshape the `lam` tensor before the statement.

```
lam = lam.reshape(batch_size, 1)
mixed_y = lam[index] * y + (1 - lam[index]) * y[index, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the sizes of the two tensors that are multiplied together don't match. Let's take `lam[index] * x` as an example. The sizes are given as:

- `x`: `torch.Size([64, 3, 256, 256])`
- `lam[index]`: `torch.Size([64])`

In order to multiply them together they should have the same size, where `lam[index]` uses the same value for the `[3, 256, 256]` per batch, since you want to multiply every element in that batch with the same value, but being different for each batch.

```py
lam[index].view(batch_size, 1, 1, 1).expand_as(x)
# => Size: torch.Size([64, 3, 256, 256])
```

`.expand_as(x)` repeats the singular dimensions so that it has the same size as x, see the [`.expand()` documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.expand) for details.

You don't need to expand the tensor, because PyTorch does that automatically for you if there are singular dimensions. That is known as broadcasting: [PyTorch -  Broadcasting Semantics](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html). So it's enough to have a size of `torch.Size([64, 1, 1, 1])` to multiply it with `x`.

```py
lam[index].view(batch_size, 1, 1, 1) * x
```

The same applies to `y` but with a size of `torch.Size([64, 1])`, since `y` has size `torch.Size([64, 3474])`.

```py
mixed_x = lam[index].view(batch_size, 1, 1, 1) * x + (1 - lam[index]).view(batch_size, 1, 1, 1) * x[index, :]
mixed_y = lam[index].view(batch_size, 1) * y + (1 - lam[index]).view(batch_size, 1) * y[index, :]
```

Just a small side note, `lam[index]` only rearranges the elements of `lam`, but since your created it randomly it doesn't make any difference whether you rearrange it or not. The only importance is that `x` and `y` are rearranged, just like in the original code.